# Help unlocking keypad locked iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch

My kid has an iPod touch that has locked from too many attempts to enter the passcode for 22 million seconds. He did this before and I connected to iTunes and it successfully unlocked it. However, I have subsequently upgraded the computer that iTunes was on, and, although the original hard disk is readable, I can't boot it, and can't seem to repair it. Can I install iTunes on the new computer and copy over some key files or something like that from the original iTunes install to get this device unlocked?

Comment: Please post only one question per topic, please.